# VB.NET - How can I add a custom method to linq to classes object?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I'd like to add a custom method on a linq to classes object.

I've created a DB.dbml in my project and I can retrieve data from my database:

```
Dim dc As New DBDataContext(_ConnString)
Dim u = (From u In dc.Users Where u.username = Username).FirstOrDefault
```

Now I'd like to call something like

```
u.mymethod()
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault` returns either `null` or a `User` instance in your call (*I am assuming the class name is `User`*). So define your `User` class to have a method called `mymethod` that does something. Your `xxx.dbml` file also has a code behind file that you can use to extend the classes defined in the `dbml`. These classes are marked as [partial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) and this is where you extend the class.

Here is a [good tutorial](http://blog.csainty.com/2008/01/linq-to-sql-extending-data-classes.html) although it is written in c#. If you want more help you would have to provide more code like the .dbml file content.